# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found:

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Spring - Hibernate

Newbie here, can please somebody help me locate what i'm missing. I am trying to do a onetomany relationship of payee and payor. My issue is im getting this error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class com.supportmanagement.model.Payee.getPayor()
javax.el.Util.findWrapper(Util.java:349)
javax.el.Util.findMethod(Util.java:211)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:150)
```

**List.jsp**
{payeelist} came from my controller via map.put("payeelist", payeeServices.getPayees());

```
...
<c:forEach items="${payeelist}" var="payee" varStatus="payeeindex">
        <tr>
            <td class="pad-0"> </td>
            <td><a href="/SupportManager/payee/edit/${payee.getCaseNumber()}"><c:out value="${payee.getCaseNumber()}" /></a></td>
            <td><c:out value="${payee.getLastname()}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${payee.getFirstname()}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${payee.getMiddlename()}" /></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="/SupportManager/payor/add?casenumber=${payee.getCaseNumber()}">
                ${payee.getPayor().getCaseNumber()}
            </a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="">ADD PAYMENT</a> <a href="" class="pull-right" title="Print Envelope"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a> </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
...
```

**Payee.java**

```
package com.supportmanagement.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "payeeMaster")
public class Payee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5876875389515595233L;

@Id
@Column(name = "CaseNumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String CaseNumber;

@Column(name = "Firstname")
private String Firstname;

@Column(name = "Lastname")
private String Lastname;

@Column(name = "Middlename")
private String Middlename;

@Column(name = "Address1")
private String Address1;

@Column(name = "Address2")
private String Address2;

@Column(name = "City")
private String City;

@Column(name = "State")
private String State;

@Column(name = "Zip")
private String Zip;

@Column(name = "HomePhone")
private String HomePhone;

@Column(name = "MobilePhone")
private String MobilePhone;

@Column(name = "Active")
private int Active;

@Column(name = "Comments")
private String Comments;

@Column(name = "StateCode")
private String StateCode;

@Column(name = "PA")
private int PA;

@Column(name = "OSE")
private int OSE;

@Column(name = "Envelope")
private int Envelope;

@Column(name = "AccountNumber")
private String AccountNumber;

@Column(name = "DNumber")
private String DNumber;

@Column(name = "LastModified")
private Date LastModified;

@Column(name = "ModifiedBy")
private String ModifiedBy;


private List<Payor> payor;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="Payor", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CaseNumber")
public List<Payor> getPayor() {
    return payor;
}

public void setPayor(List<Payor> payor) {
    this.payor = payor;
}

public String getCaseNumber() {
    return CaseNumber;
}

public void setCaseNumber(String caseNumber) {
    CaseNumber = caseNumber;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return Firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    Firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return Lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    Lastname = lastname;
}

public String getMiddlename() {
    return Middlename;
}

public void setMiddlename(String middlename) {
    Middlename = middlename;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return Address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    Address1 = address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return Address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    Address2 = address2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    City = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return State;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    State = state;
}

public String getZip() {
    return Zip;
}

public void setZip(String zip) {
    Zip = zip;
}

public String getHomePhone() {
    return HomePhone;
}

public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
    HomePhone = homePhone;
}

public String getMobilePhone() {
    return MobilePhone;
}

public void setMobilePhone(String mobilePhone) {
    MobilePhone = mobilePhone;
}

public int getActive() {
    return Active;
}

public void setActive(int active) {
    Active = active;
}

public String getComments() {
    return Comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    Comments = comments;
}

public String getStateCode() {
    return StateCode;
}

public void setStateCode(String stateCode) {
    StateCode = stateCode;
}

public int getPA() {
    return PA;
}

 public void setPA(int pA) {
    PA = pA;
}

public int getOSE() {
    return OSE;
}

public void setOSE(int oSE) {
    OSE = oSE;
}

public int getEnvelope() {
    return Envelope;
}

public void setEnvelope(int envelope) {
    Envelope = envelope;
}

public String getAccountNumber() {
    return AccountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
    AccountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public String getDNumber() {
    return DNumber;
}

public void setDNumber(String dNumber) {
    DNumber = dNumber;
}

public Date getLastModified() {
    return LastModified;
}

public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
    LastModified = lastModified;
}

public String getModifiedBy() {
    return ModifiedBy;
}

public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
    ModifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}


}
```

**Payor.java**

```
package com.supportmanager.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "payorMaster")
public class Payor implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1896406931521329889L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "PayorID")
private Integer PayorID;

@Column(name = "CaseNumber")
private String CaseNumber;

@Column(name = "PayorFirstname")
private String PayorFirstname;

@Column(name = "PayorLastname")
private String PayorLastname;

@Column(name = "PayorMiddlename")
private String PayorMiddlename;

@Column(name = "PayorAddress1")
private String PayorAddress1;

@Column(name = "PayorAddress2")
private String PayorAddress2;

@Column(name = "PayorCity")
private String PayorCity;

@Column(name = "PayorState")
private String PayorState;

@Column(name = "PayorZip")
private String PayorZip;

@Column(name = "PayorHomePhone")
private String PayorHomePhone;

@Column(name = "PayorMobilePhone")
private String PayorMobilePhone;

@Column(name = "PayorActive")
private int PayorActive;

@Column(name = "PayorComments")
private String PayorComments;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CaseNumber")
private List<Payee> payee;

public Integer getPayorID() {
    return PayorID;
}

public void setPayorID(Integer payorID) {
    PayorID = payorID;
}

public String getCaseNumber() {
    return CaseNumber;
}

public void setCaseNumber(String caseNumber) {
    CaseNumber = caseNumber;
}

public String getPayorFirstname() {
    return PayorFirstname;
}

public void setPayorFirstname(String payorFirstname) {
    PayorFirstname = payorFirstname;
}

public String getPayorLastname() {
    return PayorLastname;
}

public void setPayorLastname(String payorLastname) {
    PayorLastname = payorLastname;
}

public String getPayorMiddlename() {
    return PayorMiddlename;
}

public void setPayorMiddlename(String payorMiddlename) {
    PayorMiddlename = payorMiddlename;
}

public String getPayorAddress1() {
    return PayorAddress1;
}

public void setPayorAddress1(String payorAddress1) {
    PayorAddress1 = payorAddress1;
}

public String getPayorAddress2() {
    return PayorAddress2;
}

public void setPayorAddress2(String payorAddress2) {
    PayorAddress2 = payorAddress2;
}

public String getPayorCity() {
    return PayorCity;
}

public void setPayorCity(String payorCity) {
    PayorCity = payorCity;
}

public String getPayorState() {
    return PayorState;
}

public void setPayorState(String payorState) {
    PayorState = payorState;
}

public String getPayorZip() {
    return PayorZip;
}

public void setPayorZip(String payorZip) {
    PayorZip = payorZip;
}

public String getPayorHomePhone() {
    return PayorHomePhone;
}

public void setPayorHomePhone(String payorHomePhone) {
    PayorHomePhone = payorHomePhone;
}

public String getPayorMobilePhone() {
    return PayorMobilePhone;
}

public void setPayorMobilePhone(String payorMobilePhone) {
    PayorMobilePhone = payorMobilePhone;
}

public int getPayorActive() {
    return PayorActive;
}

public void setPayorActive(int payorActive) {
    PayorActive = payorActive;
}

public String getPayorComments() {
    return PayorComments;
}

public void setPayorComments(String payorComments) {
    PayorComments = payorComments;
}

}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
....
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.supportmanagement.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="default_schema">SupportManagerDB</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
       <list>
           <value>com.supportmanagement.model.Payee</value>
           <value>com.supportmanagement.model.Payor</value>
       </list>
     </property>
</bean> 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In you jsp page you use:

```
${payee.getPayor().getCaseNumber()}
```

Now.. `getPayor()` returns a `List<Payor>` and a List does not have the `getCaseNumber()` method.

You can get a certain Payor from the list and then invoke the method:

```
${payee.payor[index].caseNumber}
```

Where `index` is a hardcode value or a variable.

Comment: thank for reply, however, the issue persist with now istead of method not found, its now property not found 'javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'payor' not found on type com.supportmanagement.model.Payee'

Comment: Not sure if that's the case but your Pryor . payee should not be a list but Payee type